# List style is broken on Developer's Story page

Tags: bug, developer-story

The list style doesn't look right on the Developer's Story page (list created with pure markdown)

[image: list style on Developer's Story page]

Can this be changed to not look so weird? Maybe remove the bullets?

Comment: Maybe remove the `<center>`? (I think this might have been suggested before…)